I have installed cmake with pip on a Windows but when I try to use it when installing a Python library randomly, it's not accessing it
So I need to download a Python library randomly and when it's building the "wheel" for MulticoreTSNE it gets an error
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
        File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
        File "C:\Users\maggie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\cmake.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'

      Error: Cannot find cmake. Install cmake, e.g. `pip install cmake`.
      [end of output]


So it's finding cmake.exe, going into it but not finding the module 'cmake.'
If it helps, I'm working on a Lenova laptop with a Windows set up and I have tried manually downloading and installing cmake, uninstalling and reinstalling and downgrading the library but nothing is working. I should have been able to build the wheel.

this smells like a bug in MulticoreTSNE; i can't pip it myself, but with different errors. report it there.
